# Distinct count of 2 variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has columns `id` and `status` (`failed`, `success`) and `status_id`. Failure entries are redundant until a success reponse is saved. How to fetch distinct success and failure count failure attempts to be counted only once?

Query I tried:

```
select 
    sum(case when status_id in (1,2,3,4) then 1 else 0 end) as success, 
    sum(case when status_id in (5,6,7,8) then 1 else 0 end) as failed
from test
```

This query works but failed attempts are counted twice

| id | status_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 5 | failed |
| 123 | 1 | success |
| 123 | 7 | failed |
| 123 | 5 | failed |

desired output success - 1 failure - 2

Comment: Sample data in the form of input and output would greatly help your question.

Comment: Provide some sample data as CERATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the unique status_id's might work.

```
select 
 COUNT(DISTINCT case when status_id in (1,2,3,4) then status_id end) as success, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT case when status_id in (5,6,7,8) then status_id end) as failed
from test
```

Answer (score 1):

To count each success/fail only once, do `select distinct` in a *derived table* before aggregating:

```
select 
    sum(case when status_id in (1,2,3,4) then 1 else 0 end) as success, 
    sum(case when status_id in (5,6,7,8) then 1 else 0 end) as failed
from (select distinct status_id from test) dt
```